# Clear invalid input field only

Tags: javascript

[Visualforce page] I have 3 input fields with class name **rowStyle3** and it accepts numberic character only.
When the user enters a non-numeric character, I want the only invalid input field is cleared.
please help me to correct code snippet below.
Thanks a lot

```
         <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on("change", ".rowStyle3", function() {
        $('.rowStyle3').each(function() {
          var num = $(this).val();
          if(num != "" && isNaN(num)){
             $(".rowStyle3").val(''); -> All values of input fields will be cleared if one of them is invalid                             
            alert("Allow numbers only !");               
          } 
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Uhhhhh... Why not just use `<input type="number" />` or `<input type="tel" />` as appropriate?

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question in a roundabout way: you're already correctly using `$(this).val();` to get the value of this specific input. Why are you having trouble setting the value of that specific input?

Comment: I replaced  $(".rowStyle3").val(''); with $(this).val(''); and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".rowStyle3", function() {
    $('.rowStyle3').each(function(row) {
      var num = row.val();
      if(num != "" && isNaN(num)){
        row.val('');                       
        alert("Allow numbers only !");               
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

Instead of doing $.(this) you can use the enumerated value of the foreach.

Comment: Any particular reason why you'd want to check all of the `.rowStyle3` elements inside the `change` event, when, by definition, only one of them could possibly have changed - ie. the one referenced by `event.target` ;)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me. ERROR:「Uncaught TypeError: row.val is not a function」. Then I replaced  $(".rowStyle3").val(''); with $(this).val(''); and it worked !

Answer (score -1):

You can use ValidityState to check whether input element is invalid or not:

```
if (!inputElement.validity.valid) {
    inputElement.value = '';
}
```

This checks whether the inputElement input is invalid, if so, it clears it. InputElement should be something like (given that your input id is `name`):

```
inputElement = document.getElementById("name")
```

Comment: Bad idea. Terrible UX and should not be done.

Comment: The OP did not ask for a good practice, nor am I saying it is, but it solves the OP's question.

Comment: Except it doesn't because I can tell from the question that OP isn't using proper HTML5 form input types, so `validity.valid` will always be true, never false. If OP instead used proper HTML5 inputs, there would be no need for any of their code!

Comment: Huh, he didn't provide that information, I didn't deduce that.